# TypeError Ember.js

Tags: ember.js, routes, typeerror

So i'm still a beginner when it comes to Ember and right now i'm trying to understand the subclass DS.Model from Ember-data. So for some reason it gives the following error when I route to posts:

***Error while processing route: posts undefined is not a function TypeError: undefined is not a function***

```
App = Ember.Application.create();


App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
    revision: 12,
    //where do we have to look for those records?
    adapter: 'DS.FixtureAdapter'

});
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('posts'); 
    this.resource('about');

});


App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    //we're returning all the data that our application knows about
    model: function() {
        return App.Post.find();
    }

});

App.Post = DS.Model.extend({
title: DS.attr('string'),
author: DS.attr('string'),
intro: DS.attr('string'),
extended: DS.attr('string'),
publishedAt: DS.attr('date')
});


App.Post.FIXTURES = [{
  id: '1',
  title: "Rails is Omakase",
  author: "d2h" ,
  date: new Date('12-27-2012'),
  excerpt: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world. Places where in order to eat, you must first carefully look over the menu of options to order exactly what you want.",
  body: "I want this for my ORM, I want that for my template language, and let's finish it off with this routing library. Of course, you're going to have to know what you want, and you'll rarely have your horizon expanded if you always order the same thing, but there it is. It's a very popular way of consuming software.\n\nRails is not that. Rails is omakase."
}, {
  id: '2',
  title: "The Parley Letter",
  author: "d2h" ,
  date: new Date('12-24-2012'),
  excerpt: "My [appearance on the Ruby Rogues podcast](http://rubyrogues.com/056-rr-david-heinemeier-hansson/) recently came up for discussion again on the private Parley mailing list.",
  body: "A long list of topics were raised and I took a time to ramble at large about all of them at once. Apologies for not taking the time to be more succinct, but at least each topic has a header so you can skip stuff you don't care about.\n\n### Maintainability\n\nIt's simply not true to say that I don't care about maintainability. I still work on the oldest Rails app in the world."  
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the future you should post the rest of the stack trace with the error and indicate what line the error happens on. It's really hard for us to track down errors when we don't know *where* they're happening.

Fortunately, your code isn't too complicated and I've seen enough Ember code to guess that you're calling an old method on your model. Finding records using `App.Post.find()` has been deprecated for a very long time now (and it looks like it's been removed as well). You should be using `this.get('store').find('post')` instead.

Comment: ember documentation still using App.Post.find() which is very confusing. Either this.get('store') or this.store is better.

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation that still uses the `find` method on models? That should definitely be changed.

Comment: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_setupController . you can see some of them down below

Comment: Thank you, I'll submit a pull request to change that and remove the confusion.